# Change of Variable finding simple bounds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

I have a very simple problem that I've solved before (and it gave me a lot of trouble then) and I somehow can not come up with the right bound again.

In Michael Corral's book he uses a change of variable transformation to make $x = \frac{1}{2}(u+v)$ and $y = \frac{1}{2}(v-u)$.

The original substitutions are:
$x - y = u$

$x + y = v$

The bounds on the $x,y$ plane are $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $x = 1-y$
Setting x to $0$ I can come up with the first bound of $u = -v$
I did so by plugging in $0$ for $x$ and $\frac{1}{2}(v-u)$ for $y$ and set it equal to $u$
i.e. $u = -\frac{1}{2}(v-u)$ It also works simply pluggin in the numbers.

But the second bound for when $x = 1-y$ should be $u = v$
When plugging in I always get $0$ (i.e. the u's go away)
or I get $v = 1$ which is a correct line but I have no bound for u on this?
I'm doing something wrong and I'd be so grateful if you could help me out.
I have a total black out here.
I weirdly am super comfortable with polar and spherical substitution bounds but they don't apply here.

Thank you very much!

Edit: also if someone could recommend a ressource that has lot's of practice for finding these bounds that'd be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your region on $xy-$plane is bounded by a right angled triangle with boundaries $x=0, y=0 $ and $x+y=1$. You just need to know the boundaries of the transformed region in $uv-$plane using the given transformations:

> $x-y=u$ and $x+y=v$

- $x=0$ maps to $u=-y, v=y$ or equivalently $v=-u$
- $y=0$ maps to $u=x, v=x$ or equivalently $v=u$
- $x+y=1$ maps to $v=1$

> So the new transformed region is a triangle in $uv-$plane bounded by the edges $v=-u, v=u$ and $v=1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very simple and I get the correct bounds. So you didn't even need to translate the line $y = 1-x$?

Comment: Oh sorry. I now get it, you needed that line too but it was for a different bound. I understand my mistake now somewhat. I was hoping to get the $-v$ bound from the line $x+y = 1$ when in reality I needed a different line for that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You just need to determine the boundaries of the form $\phi(u,v)=0$ from the boundaries of original region $R$.